# SQL Server : select with an extra condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, conditional-statements, where-clause

I need a `SELECT` statement acting like:

```
Select 
    ...
    a = sum(column1.value)
    b = sum(column1.value) if (column2 = x)
    ....
from
   {TABLE with WHERE, GROUP etc}
```

to make it more clear:

```
columnA columnB
    3      2
    4      7
    8      1
    2      2
a=sum(columnA)
b=sum(columnA) if columnB=2
result: a=17, b=5
```

Trying with `CASE` but it doesn't work. Is there any way different from defining in `FROM` section `join TABLE AS alt ON(...) where column=x` ?

Comment: Can you add sample table data, and expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    columnA INT,
    columnB INT
)

INSERT INTO @temp (columnA, columnB)
VALUES (3, 2),(4, 7),(8, 1),(2, 2)

SELECT
      SUM(columnA)
    , SUM(CASE WHEN columnB = 2 THEN columnA END)
FROM @temp
```

Comment: I suppose that's it -  if  I have SUM do i must use SUM(COUNT(CASE part))?

Comment: your question a bit unclear for me... please provide a some details in your question

Comment: please provide data and expected result

Comment: I updated the question to make it clear, Your answer was perfectly what I was looking for